# bluetooth internet / DUN (network-manager) only works with phone newly started

Tags: network-manager, bluetooth, broadband

I connect to mobile internet over bluetooth and the Nokia C7 phone. The bluetooth connection works successfully when the phone is freshly started (i.e. I click on the connection, properly set-up, in the nm-applet and it connects), but when not, I get this in dmesg:

```
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) starting connection 'Vodafone Predefinito'
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 28 21:28:16 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Dec 28 21:28:20 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8 94:20:53:D9:C8:C8/bluetooth) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Will connect via DUN.
Dec 28 21:28:20 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8/bluetooth) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) waiting for modem to appear.
Dec 28 21:28:20 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) opening serial port...
Dec 28 21:28:20 falx kernel: [23928.016873] rfcomm_tty_ioctl: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) closing serial port...
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) serial port closed
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) opening serial port...
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (Generic): GSM modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4 claimed port rfcomm0
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx kernel: [23928.827280] rfcomm_tty_ioctl: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) closing serial port...
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) serial port closed
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8/bluetooth) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) modem found.
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) opening serial port...
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/5: state changed (disabled -> enabling)
Dec 28 21:28:21 falx kernel: [23929.158953] rfcomm_tty_ioctl: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/5: state changed (enabling -> enabled)
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/5: state changed (enabled -> registered)
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <warn> GSM connection failed: (32) Unknown registration status response
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'unknown') [50 120 1]
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> Marking connection 'Vodafone Predefinito' invalid.
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <warn> Activation (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8) failed.
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: <info> (94:20:53:D9:C8:C8): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: nm_system_iface_flush_routes: assertion `ifindex > 0' failed
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx NetworkManager[1031]: nm_system_iface_flush_addresses: assertion `ifindex > 0' failed
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) closing serial port...
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (rfcomm0) serial port closed
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  (tty/rfcomm0): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/5: state changed (registered -> disabled)
Dec 28 21:28:22 falx modem-manager[998]: mm_generic_gsm_update_signal_quality: assertion `self != NULL' failed
```

When the phone is restarted, the connection works. I had the same problem with other provider (Orange in Austria), and had no problems with other phone with the same (Vodafone) provider.

I have found no C7 posts mentioning such problems, so I assume it works fine under windows. Any hints?

(I am running up-to-date Ubuntu 11.10)

Answer (score 1):

Was discovered as modemmanager's problem parsing the phone's response, see [gnome bug #667869](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667869) or [launchpad bug #916038](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/916038).